# Any ideas on how to fill a blank sidebar?

Tags: website-design

I would like to have some suggestions on how to fill my sidebar empty space on a feed aggregator. One solution may be advertising, but for now advertising is not acceptable in the page.

A second solution might be to increase the width of the right side. This makes the page hard to read.

A third solution may be to show something like "top posts" but it makes the whole page a mess. Articles on the left, articles on the right.

For now I have a small graphic at the top of it saying "we need your opinions" because it is a new website.

Thank you for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: i fear this question gonna be closed you should read http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq...

Comment: its Brainstorming or idea gathering, and i think mods gonna close this...

Comment: I'm leaving this open. It isn't asking what to do with the site in general, but a specific area of the site. The question has led to an unexpected but valid theme: put the white space down and back away slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be filled?

Seriously. Is it necessary to jam every pixel full of *stuff*? Can't the design have some white space to breathe?

Besides, that sidebar is going to be lost to banner blindness anyway. I say leave it alone.

Answer (score 3):

Leave the space dude, cramming looks worse than white space.

Comment: I agree. If you want to "fix" the white space, move half of the column width to the right side (i.e. center the content column).

Answer (score 1):

I find sidebars to be best placed on the right side for sites like this (ie, sites where there are *lots* of thumbnail images on the left). Mainly because the text is already left-aligned and ragged-right, so any whitespace on the right seems to look just fine.

However, if you must use a left-sidebar: you could implement a fixed navigation menu.

Here's some inspiration for your sidebar:

- [Designing a creative and useful sidebar](http://veryinspirational.com/blog/web-design-blog/2010/06/07/designing-a-creative-and-useful-sidebar/)
- [20+ Examples of Fantastic Fixed-Position Navigation](http://designshack.net/articles/inspiration/20-examples-of-fantastic-fixed-position-navigation)

Comment: Thank you for this great links. The "bad thing" is that I have a top navigation and my links are only 3. I will get it to the left site to see how it looks like

Comment: You could add some social networking "share" links in there as well.